# What's the best way to optimize the case statements?

Tags: mysql, sql

For example..
I have three case statements, the values of which i want to save it in a variable..

```
Select
    Case when 1 then variable='123' else
    case when 2 then variable='456' else
    case when 3 then variable='123456'
from 
table X where 
some conditions ;
```

Comment: What exactly do you think needs optimising here?

Comment: Using some better commands than case statements ? Better way to assign the values, and my case statement contains complex conditions so i feel case doesn't provide me such performance..

Comment: In your example, this is probably the best way to do it.  Perhaps with your complex conditions there would be a better way, but we don't know what those conditions are.

Comment: Do you suggest DECODE statement or COALASCE over case statements ?

Answer (score 0):

try this for example

```
Select x.field,
    Case x.value 
    when 1 then '123'
    when 2 then '456'
    when 3 then '123456'
    ELSE '789'
    END AS variable
from 
table X where 
some conditions ;
```